# сделанное _за_ сегодня

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как лучше,

> Я люблю вспоминать сделанное сегодня

или

> Я люблю вспоминать сделанное *за* сегодня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. Ведь одно из значений слова — "текущий день". Вспоминать сделанное за текущий день.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта вынуждают задуматься, в тот ли день, когда что-то сделано, о нём вспоминают: не сразу можно сообразить, что "сегодня" нужно отнести к прошлому, которое ещё и повторяться способно. Видимо, первая реакция при чтении - примерить "сегодня" к текущему моменту. Проще сказать так:

```
Я люблю вспоминать сделанное за день.
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сформулировал:

> Я люблю вспоминать, что было сделано за сегодня.